# If a value in column M equals x then column A should Equal Column E

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to start at the top of column L then go down row by row until the last row.

- If the value in column L = 8 then copy the value from column E into column A.
- If the value of column L = 7 then copy the value from column E into column B.

The error I receive is:

> Method Range of Object_Global failed (1004)

```vb
    Sub CopyVals()

    Dim lngLoop As Long, lngRow As Long

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If Range("L" & lngLoop).Value = 8 Then
            Range("E" & lngLoop).Copy Range("A" & lngLoop)

        ElseIf Range("L" & lngLoop).Value = 7 Then
            Range("E" & lngLoop).Copy Range("B" & lngLoop)
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: `lngLoop` never gets assigned any value so will always be zero. There is no such cell as L0 so there will be an error on the first pass through the loop. `lngRow` never gets used at all. You can do the whole thing with offsets so you probably don't need either of those variables

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub CopyVals()

Dim lngLoop As Long

lngLoop = 1

For lngLoop = 1 To Rows.Count
  If Cells(lngLoop, 12).Value = "8" Then Cells(lngLoop, 1).Value = Cells(lngloop, 5).Value   

  If Cells(lngLoop, 12).Value = "7" Then Cells(lngLoop, 2).Value = Cells(lngloop, 5).Value

Next lngLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: Barrowc,                                                                                                  Thank you so much for the help.  It worked perfectly and makes a lot more sense then the direction I was going toward.    It is very much appreciated.